# Rails duplicate validation errors when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have three models, Event, Address and County, that are set up like this.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :address
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true


     validates_presence_of :address
     validates_associated :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :county, :event


     validates_presence_of :county
     validates_associated :county
end

class County < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :addresses

     validates_presence_of :name, :allow_blank => false
end
```

They are all created through one form, and it works fine until it comes to validating them.
If the county is left blank, then i get 2 validation errors:

```
County can't be blank
Address is invalid
```

I can understand why this is happening, but only need the first validation error "County can't be blank".

Any ideas on how to acheive this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

1. In the Address model you have the helper method given below, **remove** it:

validates_associated :county

2. In the County model place, **add** the following:

validates_associated :addresses

EDIT:
looks like you've hit: 
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/5632-validates_associated-should-be-allowed-to-not-create-an-error#ticket-5632-2

You may want to reactive that bug ...

Answer (score 1):

### Basic solution

You can try this in your view:

```
<% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <% unless msg.end_with?('is invalid') %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But this code doesn't change `errors.count` on base model.

### Alternative solution

You can clean up `erorrs` object from unnesessary errors in your controller (or  whatever):

```
@event.errors.values.each {|v| v.delete_if{|message| message == "is invalid"} }
```

This code will produce this `errors` hash:

```
{:"address.county"=>["can't be blank"], :address=>[]}
```

So `@event.errors.count` will return `1` instead of `2`.

Comment: Thanks Viacheslav, this works fine, but I can't help feeling this must be a common problem, and there should be a more elegant solution to supress the duplicates.

Comment: Then you can remove `validates_associated :address` from your model. Event would fail to save and you drop this `is invalid` message.

Comment: Sorry Viachesla, I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: The goal was to remove the error. Your solution is in order to raise the exception still but to hide it

Comment: @NunoCosta hm, you are right. But for now it would be hard to reproduce original problem due to passed years. And here is accepted answer.